# Prevent image rotation to change viewport width

Tags: html, css

I'm applying rotation to an `img` element and this is causing the viewport to change it's width, giving the user the possibility of scrolling to sides, there is a way to change this? The images are svgs[image: viewport]

Comment: Use `overflow-x: hidden` on the wrapping element

Comment: Please, write it as an answer so i could mark it as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `overflow-x: hidden` on the wrapping element

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the SVG in a `<div>` styled to be the same height and width as your SVG element and set `overflow: hidden` on the wrapping element.

The `<div>` will hide the corners of your SVG as it rotates but none of the inner SVG circle should be clipped.